# Microsoft Graph API redirect E-Mail instead of forwarding

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I'm currently creating a tool for redirecting incoming Mails to the correct E-Mail based on the Mail-Content.

I've already done the script, but I've one behaviour what I do not like much....

I use the `/me/messages` Microsoft Graph Endpoint for reading messages and then the `/me/messages/{id}/forward` Endpoint to Forward the E-Mail [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-forward?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

It work's like a charm, but my Problem is, that the Mail is forwarded and I found no possiblity to keep the FROM-Header, ...

I want the Same behaviour as the redirect-rule in the Office365 WebMail Rule Settings does, forward the Mail without modifying anything.

I tried to create a Draft message with the same message-json and send then the message draft, but then I get an Exception, that the user account has no privileges to use this from address.

Does anyone has an idea?

I tried to create a Draft message with the same message-json and send then the message draft, but then I get an Exception, that the user account has no privileges to use this from address.

Answer (score 1):

That can't be done in the Graph currently, in OWA when you setup forwarding it sets two underlying Active Directory properties deliverAndRedirect and msExchGenericForwardingAddress. These properties aren't exposed by the Graph (either the user or mail endpoint). The only way of setting them at the moment in using the exov3 cmdlets and Set-Mailbox -ForwardingSmtpAddress. At the Message API layer you only have permission to send as the account your using (otherwise it's considered spoofing and not allowed). You could attach the message you want to forward which would then maintain the header in the attached message.

If you have application permissions and access to the target Mailboxes you could just simply upload the message to the Target rather then forwarding which would maintain the address headers eg [Microsoft Graph API mail message: Is there any option to create inbox message from a MIME, NOT as Draft?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69831433/microsoft-graph-api-mail-message-is-there-any-option-to-create-inbox-message-fr)